# How to make sure that Discord.JS bot doesn't erase all objects when restarted?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So basically, let's say I had a list like:

```
let optIn = {}
```

and I had some code like:

```
let optIn = {}

const commands = {
    optIn: PREFIX + "optIn"
}

bot.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content === commands.optIn) {
        optIn[msg.guild.id] = msg.author.id
        msg.channel.send("**WARNING** You are now going to receive messages when someone makes a new invite.")
    }
})
```

If the bot restarts, the `optIn` variable would be set to `{}`**/**`null` so then how would I make it save that guild id to that variable, even if the bot restarts?

Also, if you need the inviteCreate event code, here it is:

```
bot.on("inviteCreate", event => {
    if(!optIn[event.guild.id]) {
        event.guild.systemChannel.send("Looks like an invite was made but the server has no user to send invite alerts to. If you want to opt in, send `amඞgus:optIn` to any channel in the server.")
    } else {
        bot.users.fetch(optIn[event.guild.id]).then(r => {
            r.send("**INVITE MADE**\nAn invite was made by <@!" + event.inviter.id + ">, in a server called `" + event.guild.name + "` and the Invite URL is `" + event.url + "`.")
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: You'll need to store it somewhere; like a file or a database.

Comment: Ah yes! What do you recommend for database software? I'll give it a google and see what you respond with :)

Comment: Ok so I can use [this](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) but I need to specify a object first it seems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to connect your node.js application to a persistent database. (Your deployment probably wipes it's data on restart and redeployment)

Try Firebase? (Might be easiest)
maybe MongoDB w/ Mongoose?

You probably can't store this in local memory, unless you deployed this on a VPS or something along those lines!

Comment: `You probably can't store this in local memory, unless you deployed this on a VPS or something along those lines!` I would try this but I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sporego suggested, I actually am writing to a .json file instead, works even better and it's free.

Comment: MongoDB is free as well

Comment: Not exactly... well yeah for a free cluster. I don't want 512MB max lol.

Comment: Hm? You can just install mongodb on your server with the installation method of your choice. The available storage space is limited by your harddisk...

Comment: Oh well, I'd rather stick with what I have currently but thanks for telling me that @CherryDT.  I still need to add a read now as I deleted it before haha. I'll update you if anything goes wrong.